# No possible adding of searching engines "Ixquick" and "Startpage" to Ubuntu-Firefox (13.04/22)

Tags: 13.04, firefox, firefox-extensions

I have a problem regarding the adding of new searching engines.
To avoid Google and its data collecting, I would like to add the searching engines "Ixquick" and "Startpage" (both by the same company) to my Firefox. Instead of using cookies, both above mentioned searching engines allow to do ones settings (language, searching results etc.) and generete an URL of it. I would like to use these URLs as chooseable searching engines in the right corner of my Firefox browser, where I also can choose for instance Google, Wikipedia and so on.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with its special/customized Firefox (22).

The problem is:

1) If directly on the pages of the searching engines Ixquick and Startpage with the specially generated for me URL, I choose "Add to Firefox", then on "Install" - and nothing happens. With both the https version, which I would prefer, and the http version. So, to add these searching engines directly from their web pages to Firefox, seems not possible.

2) Then I tried to search in Firefox for "Add Ons". There, I found Ixquick and Startpage, however, not with my preferenceds, but the normal page versions, and unfortunately, just in English. But ok, as the other option (nr. 1) did not work, it would be better than to not have it. But as I click on "Install" this add ons, it is not possible and I'd always receive a message "You can only install this add on to a Mozilla based Firefox browser" (or somehow similar).

This leads me to the conclusion that maybe the special Ubuntu Firefox version has some difficulties ...?

Or would there be another option to install finally the serching engines I want to have?

Thank you for your attention and for any help in advance.

Comment: Not sure how to fix your specific problem, but have you tried duckduckgo search engine? It has all the privacy requirements you're looking for and works great for me.

Comment: Yes, I tried DuckDuckGo and sometimes use it; however, the above mentioned searching engines seem better, in my opinion. Nevertheless, thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how I use Ixquick (I don't use DuckDuckGo because of [privacy concerns](http://search.slashdot.org/story/13/07/14/0046257/duckduckgo-illusion-of-privacy) raised on Slashdot recently; also, Ixquick is Netherland-based).

1. Back up your firefox profile (just in any chance something could go wrong). Simplest option:

   ```
   cp -a ~/.mozilla ~/mozilla-backup
   ```
2. Go to the "about:config" page (type into the URL bar). Confirm that you know what you are doing.
3. Search for the setting "keyword.URL" - you can enter it in the search bar and then only this keyword will be shown.
4. Click on the `keyword.URL`, and when a text field appears, enter:

   ```
   https://ixquick.com/do/search?language=english&cat=web&query=
   ```
5. Click on OK, exit the config web page.

Now whenever you type a search query into the address bar, you will search using the Ixquick search engine and not google.